# How do i split a string in python with multiple separators?

Tags: python, arrays, string

Having this line:

```
Breathing 1:-31.145 9:-32.8942 13:-35.8225 2:-35.9872 17:-36.2135 16:-36.6343 12:-36.7487 4:-37.8538 8:-38.6924 7:-39.0389 14:-39.0697 18:-40.0523 3:-40.5393 15:-40.5825 5:-41.6323 11:-45.2976 10:-53.3063 6:-231.617
```

I want to store in an array everything except separators(`' ',':-'`)

Comment: What exactly do you want the array contents to be? Are you sure you don't want the `-`s? What is the significance of the data's structure?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i am sure i do not want the `'-'`. `array[0]==Breathing , array[1]== 1, array[2]==31.145` and so on.

Comment: did u tried regular expressions?

Comment: I would have thought `1:-31.145` becomes `1` and `-31.145` (a negative number)? Then again I have no idea what the data is..

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**: I didn't realize that `Breathing` was part of your data. In this case you'll get all strings.

Assuming:

```
b = 'Breathing 1:-31.145 9:-32.8942 13:-35.8225 2:-35.9872'
```

then this simple construct:

```
 b.replace(':-',' ').split()
```

will give:

```
['Breathing', '1', '31.145', '9', '32.8942', '13', '35.8225', '2', '35.9872']
```

*Explanation*: it replaces any `:-` with a space (`' '`). It then splits the string wherever there is a  space to get a list of strings.

To get `float` values for the numbers:

```
['Breathing'] + [float(i) for i in b.replace(':-',' ').split()[1:]]
```

results in:

```
['Breathing', 1.0, 31.145, 9.0, 32.8942, 13.0, 35.8225, 2.0, 35.9872]
```

*Explanation*: Similar as above, except `float()` is used on all of the numeric strings to convert them to floats and the 'Breathing' string is put at the start of the list.

Comment: @Levon... where is Breathing?

Comment: I think you mean `b.replace(':-', ' ')`. As it is, you're merging two digits into one.

Comment: While I admit this could be literally what the OP wants, it's hard to believe that turning '1:-31.145' into '131.145' is the right thing to do.

Comment: @DSM I agree, I was/am a bit puzzled by this too, but OP specifically mentioned `:-` as seperator ...

Comment: @Levon: read the OP's comment in reply to Karl Knechtel's comment on the post.

Comment: @acattle Right you are .. sorry!! I'll update/fix or delete my answer as appropriately -- thanks for catching that.

Comment: @Levon you gave me a great ideea! It's rough but it will work for my requirements. Replace all the `':-'` with `' '` using notepad++. Store the contents sorted only by`' '`. THANKS!

Comment: @AiureaAdicatotYO Sorry, I didnt' realize that `Breathing` was part of your data - I fixed my answer.

Comment: @AiureaAdicatotYO If any one of these answers solved your problem in a way *you* can best understand/use, i.e., in a better way, you should consider [**accepting it** by clicking the checkmark next to the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). This will give you and the answerer both some rep points and also mark this problem as solved.

Answer (score 5):

The [`re.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) is one simple way to do this - in this case, you want to split on the set of separator characters:

```
>>> import re
>>> thestring = "Breathing 1:-31.145 9:-32.8942 13:-35.8225 2:-35.9872 17:-36.2135 16:-36.6343 12:-36.7487 4:-37.8538 8:-38.6924 7:-39.0389 14:-39.0697 18:-40.0523 3:-40.5393 15:-40.5825 5:-41.6323 11:-45.2976 10:-53.3063 6:-231.617"
>>> re.split(r"[ :\-]+", thestring)
['Breathing', '1', '31.145', '9', '32.8942', '13', '35.8225', '2', '35.9872', '17', '36.2135', '16', '36.6343', '12', '36.7487', '4', '37.8538', '8', '38.6924', '7', '39.0389', '14', '39.0697', '18', '40.0523', '3', '40.5393', '15', '40.5825', '5', '41.6323', '11', '45.2976', '10', '53.3063', '6', '231.617']
```

`[]` defines a character set, containing a space, `:`, and `-` (which needs escaped, as it's used for ranges like `[a-z]`) - the `+` after the character set means one-or-more

To split explicitly on either a space, or `:-`, you can use the `|` or regex thingy:

```
>>> re.split(":-| ", thestring)
['Breathing', '1', '31.145', ...]
```

As I mentioned in the comment on the question, I would have thought the separator would just be `:` and the `-` indicates a negative number..

Comment: You're regex would be a little more easy to read if you used a raw string (you wouldn't have to double escape the -).  Also, this will split on `"- "` or `" :"` ... which is probably perfectly acceptable, but doesn't quite match the request in the question.

Comment: @mgilson Good point - added solution which splits on literal `:-`, and used raw-string to avoid `\\\\`ness

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])`

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not specified or -1, then there is no limit on the number of splits (all possible splits are made).

Applied

```
>> ' 1  2   3  '.split()
['1', '2', '3']
```

in "tandem" with `str.replace(old, new[, count])`

> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

Applied

```
>>> a = 'h!e!l!l!o! w!o!r!l!d!'
>>> a.replace('!','')
'hello world'
```

Applied to your scenario:

```
>> 'Breathing 1:-31.145 9:-32.8942 13:-35.8225 2:-35.9872 17:-36.2135 16:-36.6343
              12:-36.7487 4:-37.8538 8:-38.6924 7:-39.0389 14:-39.0697 18:-40.0523
              3:-40.5393 15:-40.5825 5:-41.6323 11:-45.2976 10:-53.3063 
              6:-231.617'.replace(':-',' ').split(' ')

 ['Breathing', '1', '31.145', '9', '32.8942', '13', '35.8225', '2', 
   '35.9872', '17', '36.2135', '16', '36.6343', '12', '36.7487', '4', '37.8538', 
   '8', '38.6924', '7', '39.0389', '14', '39.0697', '18', '40.0523', '3', 
   '40.5393', '15', '40.5825', '5', '41.6323', '11', '45.2976', 
   '10', '53.3063', '6', '231.617']
```

**All the definition are taken from manual**

Comment: Why use `rsplit()` over `split()`?

Comment: @Lattyware : just a mistyping :)

Comment: @acattle : take a better look

Comment: @AiureaAdicatotYO : they're removed. Take a look to output

Comment: @acattle So important to deserve a -1 and no +1(s) ?

Comment: You're copying and pasting documentation without context or explanation about how this applies to the OP's problem. You're answer is much too long and too confusing.

Comment: @acattle : i don't think so. I provide a fit-solution to his needs and it works. Moreover, i paste the documentation so that user can understand cleary what's happen at every passage. To me, is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex is probably the best way to do this:

```
import re
re.split('\s+|:-','Breathing 1:-135')
```

This gives you `['Breathing', '1', '135']`, which is exactly what you want. Here, the `\s+` stands for one or more whitespaces, the `|` stands for "or", and `:-` is matched literally.

Edit: @mgilson gave the same answer. Anyways, you may want to look at the [documentation for python regex](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
array=re.split(r'\s+|:-',mystring)
```

In the regex, `\s+` matches whitespace whereas `:-` matches that literal sequence in the string.  the pipe (`|`) is re's way of saying match if either of these conditions matches.

Of course, you could change `"\s+"` to `"\s"` or even `" "` if you wanted to be sure to split on a single space as requested in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite what you asked, but it might be what you need anyway ;-)

```
lines = ['Breathing 1:-31.145 9:-32.8942 13:-35.8225 2:-35.9872 17:-36.2135 16:-36.6343 12:-36.7487 4:-37.8538 8:-38.6924 7:-39.0389 14:-39.0697 18:-40.0523 3:-40.5393 15:-40.5825 5:-41.6323 11:-45.2976 10:-53.3063 6:-231.617']

data = {}
for line in lines:
    line = line.split()   # split on spaces
    values = (s.split(':-') for s in line[1:])
    data[line[0]] = {int(t):float(val) for t,val in values}
```

results in

```
data = {
    'Breathing': {
        1: 31.145,
        2: 35.9872,
        3: 40.5393,
        4: 37.8538,
        5: 41.6323,
        6: 231.617,
        7: 39.0389,
        8: 38.6924,
        9: 32.8942,
        10: 53.3063,
        11: 45.2976,
        12: 36.7487,
        13: 35.8225,
        14: 39.0697,
        15: 40.5825,
        16: 36.6343,
        17: 36.2135,
        18: 40.0523
    }
}
```

You can then access it as

```
data['Breathing'][2]   # -> 35.9872
```